# How to get the data at the right after finding the max in a column

Tags: excel, max, formula

I have a set of data with 2 columns, col A is date and col B is time. 
I would like to have a formula that find the latest date and then also the latest time in col B.

As shown below, the latest time will be 8/11/2016 8:57
Using max can get the latest date then should i combine it with match and index to get the cell at the right??

[image]

Comment: Yes - Match + Index should do it.

Comment: yes, what is the exact formula to do it? i am not too familiar with match and index. thanks!

Comment: If latest date/time is placed at the top of rows, why do need formula?

Comment: i got what you guys are saying, i have multiple sheet of data, how about if it is not sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

`=TEXT((MAX($A$2:$A$9)), "d/m/yyyy") & " " & TEXT(MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$9=MAX($A$2:$A$9)),($B$2:$B$9))), "h:m")`

And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Since you need 2 sets of values, date and time, this formula gives you both.

Comment: @bzimor I'm using a non-sorted table of values

Comment: oh, sorry I missed max() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use AGGREGATE

```
=AGGREGATE(14,0,A2:A13+B2:B13,1)
```

You need to format the cell with datetime format for it to display right. I have mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss in my sample.

[image]